# How to make an app do authentication between 2 NFC phone?

Tags: authentication, nfc

I am using a Galaxy Nexus and is trying to make an app that will authenticate with each other using NFC, but I do not know where to begin. Is there any tutorial out there that will be able to help me out?

Comment: Authentication is a very vague term, and a suitable solution depends what you can deploy on each side, if you decide to trust the device OS, and if you wish to protect against eavesdropping (you would usually). Also it will depend upon what the authentication will be used for. Can you please elaborate a little ?

Comment: Like reading of the NFC tag to see if the correct tag is being scanned. If its the right one, it will unlock the phone.

Comment: Authentification in this context would mean that you prove that the NFC tag is genuine, some way or another (e.g. using crypto challenge/response protocol). Otherwise it is just capturing an event which anyone could produce or replicate. Your request is still very unclear.